# How to get number of Grid rows before applied filter

Tags: vaadin-flow

I have a Grid with column filters applied. After calling Grid.getListDataView().getItemCount() immediately after population, I get the correct number. However, if I call it again after a refresh, the number I get is after the filter has been applied. For example, if the Grid is presented with filters applied and displays 5 visible records (while hiding 10 records), the getItemCount() method returns 15. But upon refreshing the Grid, the number changes to 5 - which is the number of visible records after the filter has been applied, not the expected 15.

How can I retrieve the number of items in the Grid before the column filters have been applied?

Comment: I should add: This is for Vaadin 23.

Comment: Store the total size before you apply the filters.

Answer (score 1):

This is intended behavior of the method, you can see this by reading its JavaDoc.

```
/**
 * Get the full item count **with filters** if any set. As the item count might
 * change at any point, it is recommended to add a listener with the
 * {@link #addItemCountChangeListener(ComponentEventListener)} method
 * instead to get notified when the item count has changed.
 *
 * @return filtered item count
 * @see #addItemCountChangeListener(ComponentEventListener)
 */
```

Comment: OK - so there is no way to get this info from the Grid (via any sort of data view or data handler).  I see the suggested work-around from Knoobie (Thanks!) and can use that but it would be nice to be able to query the Grid in some dynamic fashion to get more info regarding the state of the data it is presenting (instead of having to apply a work-around).  But thanks for the quick response!